# Please help to improve my CSS code

Tags: css

I wrote some css codes but was told that I need to improve/optimize them, is there any idea? Thanks!

```
        .box-popup {
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
            color: ‘#ccc’;
            z-index: 1000;
            top: -72px;
            left: 165px;
            width: 250px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: ‘#ccc’;
            padding: 30px 50px 40px 50px;
            border-radius: 3px;
           transition: opacity 400ms ease-in-out;
           -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in-out;
           -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in-out;
        }
```

Comment: `color` property should not have color value in quotes. it should be, `color:#ccc`. Plus you can minify your CSS by removing spaces or directly go to [css-minifier](https://cssminifier.com/).

Comment: How to "optimize" your css would depend, to some degree, on your markup. The markup will determine any css properties that may be obsolete. Share your html.

Comment: What is the difference between '#ccc' and #ccc??

Comment: @WangPeiTheDancer the latter is the valid css property.

Comment: @nick why is not necessary to use positon:absolute??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reviewed code: (*check the comments*)

```
    .box-popup {
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        color: #ccc;  /* removed quotes */
        z-index: 1;  /* try not to use higher z-index values unnecessarily */
        top: -72px;
        left: 165px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #ccc; /* removed quotes or use currentColor if the color is same as of color property */
        padding: 30px 50px 40px 50px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out; /* used 'seconds' unit just to make it shorter */
        -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I tried to remove the positon:absolute, the it looked differently, so what does positon:absolute control about here?

Comment: @WangPeiTheDancer please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position), you will understand it better.